# Eon Blue Apocolypse

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, music

I'm beginning to feel a little better today and had quite the energetic morning. I got up, worked out, ate breakfast, sped to work; you know, the usual. On the way to work, I enjoyed listening to the sounds of my engine as I blared one of my favorite bands. Can you guess which band it is?

> Some say the end is near; clearing out what could've been.
>
> My shadow's shedding skin; I've been picking, scabs again.
>
> There's a shadow, just behind me; shrouding every step I take.
>
> Something has to change; I can help you change.
>
> Mother Mary, won't you whisper; I am just an imbecile.
>
> I will only complicate you; trust in me and fall as well.
>
> Feed my will, to feel my moment; drawing way outside the lines.

This is quite the wordplay riddle, and the band can be found so long as you look hard enough. Don't just tell me the name of the band though, explain how they relate to the riddle entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all look like song lyrics from the band

> Tool.

Title: Eon Blue Apocalypse

> Is a song by Tool.

Some say the end is near;

> From their song AEnema.

clearing out what could've been.

> From their song Forty-Six & 2.

My shadow's shedding skin;

> From their song Forty-Six & 2.

I've been picking, scabs again.

> From their song Forty-Six & 2.

There's a shadow, just behind me;

> From their song Sober.

shrouding every step I take.

> From their song Sober.

Something has to change;

> From their song Stinkfist.

I can help you change.

> From their song Stinkfist.

Mother Mary, won't you whisper;

> From their song Sober.

I am just an imbecile.

> From their song Sober.

I will only complicate you;

> From their song Sober.

trust in me and fall as well.

> From their song Sober.

Feed my will, to feel my moment;

> From their song Lateralus.

drawing way outside the lines.

> From their song Lateralus.

Comment: I made that too easy; it was quite difficult to attempt blending here like I wanted to. Great job!